# How to render Direct3D scene to texture, process it with CUDA and render result to screen?

Tags: c++, cuda, directx, directx-11, direct3d

**UPDATE 1:**

I have tried (to my best knowledge) the suggestion in the comments. I have created an identical to the RTV texture

```
D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC texture_rgb_cudaDesc;
    ZeroMemory(&texture_rgb_cudaDesc, sizeof(D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC));
    texture_rgb_cudaDesc.Width = width;
    texture_rgb_cudaDesc.Height = height;
    texture_rgb_cudaDesc.MipLevels = 1;
    texture_rgb_cudaDesc.ArraySize = 1;
    texture_rgb_cudaDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;   //DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT
    texture_rgb_cudaDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
    texture_rgb_cudaDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE::D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
    texture_rgb_cudaDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_FLAG::D3D11_BIND_RENDER_TARGET;
    hr = device->CreateTexture2D(&texture_rgb_cudaDesc, nullptr, &texture_rgb_cuda);
```

Then, right at the beginning of the body of `if(cuda_enable) { ... }` I added

```
device_context->CopyResource(texture_rgb_cuda, texture_rgb);
```

and at the end

```
device_context->CopyResource(texture_rgb, texture_rgb_cuda);
```

This is done in order to see if CUDA and Direct3D are not competing for the same resource with CUDA winning. Sadly, this change has no visible effect.

---

**UPDATE 2:**

I have update my code with the suggestions from the answer from Alex below (Pastebin URL without expiration) to the best of my knowledge:

https://pastebin.com/K6K9yBXt

The result is a fully black scene (except for the ImGUI on top). If I switch to the normal rendering without the CUDA processing and get back to the CUDA processing I am getting the last view of the properly rendered scene (rotating cube with a blue background) frozen in the viewport.

---

**UPDATE 3:**

At least I am sure that the scene is properly rendered to the texture that will be loaded in CUDA for read only access:

[image: ImGui window that shows the scene as it is rendered before the CUDA processing step]

---

I am no Direct3D and CUDA expert, just keep that in mind. :D All relevant code can be found at the end. Please, let me know if you need more information.

My goal is to process the rendered scene in Torch (using `libtorch`) with an AI model (something that receives and outputs image data). My research has showed me that I need to

1. Render the scene to a texture
2. Register the texture as a CUDA graphics resource (using `cudaGraphicsD3D11RegisterResource()`)
3. Setup the memory (using `cudaMallocPitch()` and `cudaMemset()`)
4. Map the CUDA graphics resource (using `cudaGraphicsMapResources()`)
5. Convert the mapped CUDA graphics resource to a CUDA array (using `cudaGraphicsSubResourceGetMappedArray()`)
6. Convert the CUDA array to a Torch tensor (using `torch::from_blob()`)
7. Process the Torch tensor
8. Render the resulting texture to the screen

I have created a simple DirectX setup where a rotating cube with basic FX shader applied to it. In addition I have added ImGUI as a basic UI for controlling some things related to the application:

[image: Default rendering]

Next I checked out the [official CUDA sample](https://github.com/NVIDIA/cuda-samples/tree/master/Samples/5_Domain_Specific/simpleD3D11Texture) on how to map a texture (where I will render my scene to) as a CUDA resource and process it. The sample include kernels so I picked the one that seemed to be appropriate for my case, namely the [2D texture one](https://github.com/NVIDIA/cuda-samples/blob/master/Samples/5_Domain_Specific/simpleD3D11Texture/texture_2d.cu).

Initially I had a funny result (note that the multicolor hatch pattern is the result from the CUDA sample I have copied over):

[image: Running the CUDA kernels before the render call]

since I would first run my kernels and then actually render my cube (forcing me to temporarily remove `ClearRenderTargetView()` from my rendering method) and ImGUI.

By looking at the Direct3D 11 pipeline

[image: Direct3D 11 pipeline]

I got inspired and figured out I should run my kernels right after I have drawn my scene with the cube and before I have drawn the ImGUI interface (since I don't want to process that).

However, now I am stuck with the following result:

[image: Processing buffer after drawing cube but before drawing ImGUI]

Now clearly the kernel

```
__global__ void cuda_kernel_texture_2d(unsigned char *surface, int width,
                                       int height, size_t pitch, float t) {
  int x = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
  int y = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
  float *pixel;

  // in the case where, due to quantization into grids, we have
  // more threads than pixels, skip the threads which don't
  // correspond to valid pixels
  if (x >= width || y >= height) return;

  // get a pointer to the pixel at (x,y)
  pixel = (float *)(surface + y * pitch) + 4 * x;

  // populate it
  float value_x = 0.5f + 0.5f * cos(t + 10.0f * ((2.0f * x) / width - 1.0f));
  float value_y = 0.5f + 0.5f * cos(t + 10.0f * ((2.0f * y) / height - 1.0f));
  pixel[0] = 0.5 * pixel[0] + 0.5 * pow(value_x, 3.0f);  // red
  pixel[1] = 0.5 * pixel[1] + 0.5 * pow(value_y, 3.0f);  // green
  pixel[2] = 0.5f + 0.5f * cos(t);                       // blue
  pixel[3] = 1;                                          // alpha
}
```

generates new values for the pixels so anything that was before as contents gets overwritten. The issue I am facing is that, even if I were to change the kernel to just slightly alter the pixel values,

```
pixel[0] = 0.5 * pixel[0]; // red
pixel[1] = 0.5 * pixel[1]; // green
pixel[2] = 0.5 * pixel[2]; // blue
pixel[3] = 1; // alpha
```

I am still not getting my drawn scene that is supposed to be passed to the CUDA context. How would I fix that?

---

**UPDATE:** I have removed the contents of the kernel (so that I don't modify anything). The result however is just a black scene:

[image: Running empty kernel on the scene]

---

**main.cpp**

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <windowsx.h>
#include <d3d11.h>
#include <DirectXMath.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>    
#include <dxgi.h>
#include <cuda_runtime_api.h>
#include <cuda_d3d11_interop.h>
#include <helper_cuda.h>
#include "load_sample.h"

#include <imgui.h>
#include <imgui_impl_win32.h>
#include <imgui_impl_dx11.h>

#define WIN_WIDTH 800
#define WIN_HEIGHT 600

IDXGIAdapter* adapter = nullptr;
IDXGISwapChain* swapchain = nullptr;
ID3D11Device* device = nullptr;
ID3D11DeviceContext* device_context = nullptr;

ID3D11RenderTargetView* rtv_cuda = nullptr;
ID3D11DepthStencilView* buffer_depth = nullptr;

ID3D11Texture2D* texture_rgb;
ID3D11Texture2D* texture_depth;

cudaGraphicsResource* cuda_interop_resource = nullptr;
size_t texture_rgb_cuda_pitch = 0;
void* texture_rgb_cuda_linear_mem = nullptr;
bool cuda_enable = true;
int cuda_device_count = 0;

extern "C"
{
    cudaError_t cuda_texture_2d(void* surface, size_t width, size_t height, size_t pitch, float t);
}


ID3D11SamplerState* sampler_state = nullptr;
ID3D11RasterizerState* raster_state = nullptr;
ID3D11DepthStencilState* stencil_state = nullptr;
char devname[256];

ID3D11PixelShader* sample_pixel_shader = nullptr;
ID3D11VertexShader* sample_vertex_shader = nullptr;
ID3D11InputLayout* sample_vertex_layout = nullptr;
ID3D11Buffer* sample_vertex_buffer = nullptr;
ID3D11Buffer* sample_index_buffer = nullptr;
ID3D11Buffer* sample_constant_buffer = nullptr;

DirectX::XMMATRIX       matrix_world;
DirectX::XMMATRIX       matrix_view;
DirectX::XMMATRIX       matrix_projection;

bool getAdapter(IDXGIAdapter** adapter, char* devname); 
void InitCuda();
cudaError_t RunCudaKernels();
void InitD3D(HWND hWnd);
void RenderFrame(void);
void Clean(void);

static long long frame_counter;

extern LRESULT ImGui_ImplWin32_WndProcHandler(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
    HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    LPSTR lpCmdLine,
    int nCmdShow)
{
    HWND hWnd;
    HRESULT hr;
    WNDCLASSEX wc;
    std::string window_title = "CUDA Torch Direct3D Interop Demo";

    ZeroMemory(&wc, sizeof(WNDCLASSEX));

    wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WindowProc;
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)COLOR_WINDOW;
    wc.lpszClassName = "WindowClass";

    RegisterClassEx(&wc);

    RECT wr = { 0, 0, WIN_WIDTH, WIN_HEIGHT };
    auto wrStyle = (WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_SYSMENU | WS_CAPTION | WS_MINIMIZEBOX);

    hWnd = CreateWindowEx(NULL,
        "WindowClass",
        window_title.c_str(),
        wrStyle,
        300,
        300,
        wr.right - wr.left,
        wr.bottom - wr.top,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        hInstance,
        NULL);

    ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);

    try
    {
        InitCuda();
        window_title += std::string(" (") + std::string(devname) + std::string(")");
        SetWindowText(hWnd, window_title.c_str());
    }
    catch (std::exception& e)
    {
        // ...
        return 2;
    }

    try
    {
        InitD3D(hWnd);
    }
    catch (std::exception& e)
    {
        // ...
        return 1;
    }

    // Register the render buffer as a CUDA resource
    cudaError_t cr = cudaGraphicsD3D11RegisterResource(&cuda_interop_resource, texture_rgb, cudaGraphicsRegisterFlags::cudaGraphicsRegisterFlagsNone);
    if (cr != cudaSuccess)
    {
        // ...
    }
    // The registered resource can only be mapped as a texture. In order to write to it, a CUDA array is required
    RECT rect;
    int width = 0;
    int height = 0;
    if (GetWindowRect(hWnd, &rect))
    {
        width = rect.right - rect.left;
        height = rect.bottom - rect.top;
    }
    cr = cudaMallocPitch(&texture_rgb_cuda_linear_mem, &texture_rgb_cuda_pitch, width * sizeof(float) * 4, height);
    if (cr != cudaSuccess)
    {
        // ...
    }
    cr = cudaMemset(texture_rgb_cuda_linear_mem, 1, texture_rgb_cuda_pitch * height);
    if (cr != cudaSuccess)
    {
        // ...
    }

    IMGUI_CHECKVERSION();
    ImGui::CreateContext();
    ImGuiIO& io = ImGui::GetIO();
    ImGui_ImplWin32_Init(hWnd);
    ImGui_ImplDX11_Init(device, device_context);
    ImGui::StyleColorsDark();

    MSG msg;

    // Create cube sample
    hr = create_cube(device, device_context,
        &sample_vertex_layout, &sample_vertex_buffer, &sample_vertex_shader,
        &sample_index_buffer, &sample_constant_buffer, &sample_pixel_shader
    );

    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        // ...
    }

    while (TRUE)
    {
        if (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);

            if (msg.message == WM_QUIT)
                break;
        }

        // Render the frame and process with CUDA
        try
        {
            RenderFrame();
        }
        catch (std::exception& e)
        {
            // ...
        }
    }

    Clean();

    return msg.wParam;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (ImGui_ImplWin32_WndProcHandler(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam))
    {
        return true;
    }

    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_DESTROY:
    {
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    } break;
    case WM_KEYDOWN:
    {
        unsigned char keycode = static_cast<unsigned char>(wParam);
        //...
    }
    break;
    }

    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}

void InitD3D(HWND hWnd)
{
    RECT rect;
    int width = 0;
    int height = 0;
    if (GetWindowRect(hWnd, &rect))
    {
        width = rect.right - rect.left;
        height = rect.bottom - rect.top;
    }

    if (!width || !height)
    {
        // ...
        exit(1);
    }

    HRESULT hr = 0;

    DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC swapchainDesc;

    ZeroMemory(&swapchainDesc, sizeof(DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC));

    swapchainDesc.BufferCount = 1;
    swapchainDesc.BufferDesc.Width = width;
    swapchainDesc.BufferDesc.Height = height;
    swapchainDesc.BufferDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;     // use 32-bit color DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT
    swapchainDesc.BufferDesc.RefreshRate.Numerator = 60;
    swapchainDesc.BufferDesc.RefreshRate.Denominator = 1;
    swapchainDesc.BufferUsage = DXGI_USAGE_RENDER_TARGET_OUTPUT;
    swapchainDesc.OutputWindow = hWnd;
    swapchainDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
    swapchainDesc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
    swapchainDesc.Windowed = TRUE;

    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL featureLevels[] =
    {
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_1,
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_0,
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_1,
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_0
    };
    UINT numFeatureLevels = ARRAYSIZE(featureLevels);

    char devname_dx[128];
    bool device_ok = getAdapter(&adapter, devname_dx);

    DXGI_ADAPTER_DESC adapterDesc;
    adapter->GetDesc(&adapterDesc); //devid = 9436, subsysid = 177803304

    hr = D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain(
        adapter,
        D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_UNKNOWN,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        featureLevels,
        numFeatureLevels,
        D3D11_SDK_VERSION,
        &swapchainDesc,
        &swapchain,
        &device,
        NULL,
        &device_context);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        // ...
    }

    adapter->Release();
    device->GetImmediateContext(&device_context);

    hr = swapchain->GetBuffer(0, __uuidof(ID3D11Texture2D), (LPVOID*)&texture_rgb); 
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        // ...
    }

    hr = device->CreateRenderTargetView(texture_rgb, nullptr, &rtv); //backbuffer    texture_rgb, &renderDesc, &backbuffer
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        // ...
    }
    device->CreateRenderTargetView(texture_rgb, nullptr, &rtv_cuda);
    texture_rgb->Release();

    D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC depthStencilDesc;
    ZeroMemory(&depthStencilDesc, sizeof(D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC));
    depthStencilDesc.Width = width;
    depthStencilDesc.Height = height;
    depthStencilDesc.MipLevels = 1;
    depthStencilDesc.ArraySize = 1;
    depthStencilDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_D24_UNORM_S8_UINT;
    depthStencilDesc.SampleDesc.Count = swapchainDesc.SampleDesc.Count;
    depthStencilDesc.SampleDesc.Quality = swapchainDesc.SampleDesc.Quality;
    depthStencilDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE::D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
    depthStencilDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_FLAG::D3D11_BIND_DEPTH_STENCIL;
    depthStencilDesc.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
    depthStencilDesc.MiscFlags = 0;
    hr = device->CreateTexture2D(&depthStencilDesc, nullptr, &texture_depth);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        // ...
    }
    hr = device->CreateDepthStencilView(texture_depth, nullptr, &buffer_depth);

    device_context->OMSetRenderTargets(1, &rtv_cuda, buffer_depth);

    D3D11_VIEWPORT viewport;
    ZeroMemory(&viewport, sizeof(D3D11_VIEWPORT));

    viewport.TopLeftX = 0;
    viewport.TopLeftY = 0;
    viewport.Width = WIN_WIDTH;
    viewport.Height = WIN_HEIGHT;
    viewport.MinDepth = 0.0f;
    viewport.MaxDepth = 1.0f;

    device_context->RSSetViewports(1, &viewport);

    matrix_world = DirectX::XMMatrixIdentity();
    DirectX::XMVECTOR Eye = DirectX::XMVectorSet(0.0f, 4.0f, -5.0f, 0.0f);  //0 1 -5 0
    DirectX::XMVECTOR At = DirectX::XMVectorSet(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    DirectX::XMVECTOR Up = DirectX::XMVectorSet(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    matrix_view = DirectX::XMMatrixLookAtLH(Eye, At, Up);
    matrix_projection = DirectX::XMMatrixPerspectiveFovLH(DirectX::XM_PIDIV2, viewport.Width / (FLOAT)viewport.Height, 0.01f, 100.0f);

    {
        D3D11_SAMPLER_DESC samplerStateDesc;
        samplerStateDesc.Filter = D3D11_FILTER_MIN_MAG_MIP_LINEAR;
        samplerStateDesc.AddressU = D3D11_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_CLAMP;
        samplerStateDesc.AddressV = D3D11_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_CLAMP;
        samplerStateDesc.AddressW = D3D11_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_CLAMP;
        samplerStateDesc.MinLOD = 0;
        samplerStateDesc.MaxLOD = 8;
        samplerStateDesc.MipLODBias = 0;
        samplerStateDesc.MaxAnisotropy = 1;

        hr = device->CreateSamplerState(&samplerStateDesc, &sampler_state);
        if (FAILED(hr))
        {
            // ...
        }
        device_context->PSSetSamplers(0, 1, &sampler_state);
    }

    {
        D3D11_RASTERIZER_DESC rasterizerStateDesc;
        rasterizerStateDesc.FillMode = D3D11_FILL_SOLID;    //D3D11_FILL_SOLID      D3D11_FILL_WIREFRAME
        rasterizerStateDesc.CullMode = D3D11_CULL_BACK;
        rasterizerStateDesc.FrontCounterClockwise = false;
        rasterizerStateDesc.DepthBias = false;
        rasterizerStateDesc.DepthBiasClamp = 0;
        rasterizerStateDesc.SlopeScaledDepthBias = 0;
        rasterizerStateDesc.DepthClipEnable = false;
        rasterizerStateDesc.ScissorEnable = false;
        rasterizerStateDesc.MultisampleEnable = false;
        rasterizerStateDesc.AntialiasedLineEnable = false;

        hr = device->CreateRasterizerState(&rasterizerStateDesc, &raster_state);
        if (FAILED(hr))
        {
            // ...
        }
        device_context->RSSetState(raster_state);
    }

    {
        D3D11_DEPTH_STENCIL_DESC stencilDesc;
        ZeroMemory(&stencilDesc, sizeof(stencilDesc));

        stencilDesc.DepthEnable = true;
        stencilDesc.DepthWriteMask = D3D11_DEPTH_WRITE_MASK_ALL;
        stencilDesc.DepthFunc = D3D11_COMPARISON_LESS_EQUAL;

        hr = device->CreateDepthStencilState(&stencilDesc, &stencil_state);
        if (FAILED(hr))
        {
            // ...
        }
        device_context->OMSetDepthStencilState(stencil_state, 0);
    }
}


// Process a frame with CUDA and render it
void RenderFrame(void)
{
    HRESULT hr = 0;

    float color[4] = { 0.0f, 0.2f, 0.4f, 1.0f };

    device_context->ClearRenderTargetView(rtv_cuda, color); //CUDA result is cleared, we want to avoid that
    device_context->ClearDepthStencilView(buffer_depth, D3D11_CLEAR_DEPTH | D3D11_CLEAR_STENCIL, 1.0f, 0);

    static float t = 0.0f;
    static ULONGLONG timeStart = 0;
    ULONGLONG timeCur = GetTickCount64();
    if (timeStart == 0)
        timeStart = timeCur;
    t = (timeCur - timeStart) / 1000.0f;

    static float translationOffset[3] = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f };
    matrix_world = DirectX::XMMatrixRotationY(t) * DirectX::XMMatrixTranslation(translationOffset[0], translationOffset[1], translationOffset[2]);

    ConstantBuffer cb;
    cb.mWorld = DirectX::XMMatrixTranspose(matrix_world);
    cb.mView = DirectX::XMMatrixTranspose(matrix_view);
    cb.mProjection = DirectX::XMMatrixTranspose(matrix_projection);
    device_context->UpdateSubresource(sample_constant_buffer, 0, nullptr, &cb, 0, 0);

    device_context->VSSetShader(sample_vertex_shader, nullptr, 0);
    device_context->VSSetConstantBuffers(0, 1, &sample_constant_buffer);
    device_context->PSSetShader(sample_pixel_shader, nullptr, 0);
    device_context->DrawIndexed(36, 0, 0);        // 36 vertices needed for 12 triangles in a triangle list

    if (cuda_enable)
    {
        // Map resource
        cudaStream_t stream = 0;
        const int cuda_mapped_resources_count = 1;
        cudaGraphicsResource* cuda_mapped_resources[cuda_mapped_resources_count] = { cuda_interop_resource };
        cudaError_t cr = cudaGraphicsMapResources(cuda_mapped_resources_count, cuda_mapped_resources, stream);
        if (cr != cudaSuccess)
        {
            // ...
        }

        // Run CUDA kernels
        cr = RunCudaKernels();
        if (cr != cudaSuccess)
        {
            // ...
        }

        cr = cudaDeviceSynchronize();
        if (cr != cudaSuccess)
        {
            // ...
        }

        cr = cudaGraphicsUnmapResources(cuda_mapped_resources_count, cuda_mapped_resources, stream);
        if (cr != cudaSuccess)
        {
            // ...
        }
    }

    // Draw ImGUI
    ImGui_ImplDX11_NewFrame();
    ImGui_ImplWin32_NewFrame();

    ImGui::NewFrame();
    ImGui::Begin("Controls / Debug Information");
    ImGui::Text((cuda_device_count ? std::string("Found " + std::to_string(cuda_device_count) + " CUDA " + (cuda_device_count == 1 ? "device" : "devices")).c_str() : "No CUDA devices found!"));
    ImGui::Text(devname);
    ImGui::DragFloat3("Trans X/Y/Z", translationOffset, 0.1f, -5.0f, 5.0f);
    ImGui::Checkbox(std::string((cuda_enable ? "Enabled" : "Disabled") + std::string(" CUDA")).c_str(), &cuda_enable);
    ImGui::End();
    ImGui::Render();
    ImGui_ImplDX11_RenderDrawData(ImGui::GetDrawData());

    hr = swapchain->Present(0, 0);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        std::string msg = std::string("[RenderFrame] Failed to swap back with front buffer: ") + std::to_string(hr);
        throw std::exception(msg.c_str());
    }
}

void Clean(void)
{
    // TODO Clean all allocated resources from DirectX and CUDA
}


bool getAdapter(IDXGIAdapter** adapter, char* devname)
{
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;
    cudaError_t cr = cudaSuccess;
    UINT adapter_idx = 0;
    IDXGIFactory* pFactory;

    hr = CreateDXGIFactory(__uuidof(IDXGIFactory), (void**)(&pFactory));

    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        std::string msg = std::string("[getAdapter] Unable to create DXGI factory: ") + std::to_string(hr);
        throw std::exception(msg.c_str());
        return false;
    }

    for (; !(*adapter); ++adapter_idx) {
        // Get a candidate DXGI adapter
        IDXGIAdapter* pAdapter = NULL;
        hr = pFactory->EnumAdapters(adapter_idx, &pAdapter);

        if (FAILED(hr))
        {
            break;  // no compatible adapters found
        }

        // Query to see if there exists a corresponding compute device
        int cuDevice;
        cr = cudaD3D11GetDevice(&cuDevice, pAdapter);

        if (cr == cudaSuccess) {
            // If so, mark it as the one against which to create our d3d10 device
            (*adapter) = pAdapter;
            (*adapter)->AddRef();
            ++adapter_idx;
            break;
        }

        pAdapter->Release();
    }

    std::cout << "Found " << (int)adapter_idx << " D3D11 adapater(s)" << std::endl;

    pFactory->Release();

    if (!adapter) {
        std::cerr << "Unable to find a D3D11 adapater with compute capability" << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    DXGI_ADAPTER_DESC adapterDesc;
    (*adapter)->GetDesc(&adapterDesc);
    std::cout << "Found a D3D11 adapater with compute capability" << std::endl;

    return true;
}


// This function initializes and prepares CUDA for use
void InitCuda()
{
    int nGraphicsGPU = 0;
    bool bFoundGraphics = false;

    // This function call returns 0 if there are no CUDA capable devices.
    cudaError_t cr = cudaGetDeviceCount(&cuda_device_count);

    if (cr != cudaSuccess)
    {
        std::string msg = std::string("[InitCuda] Failed retrieve number of CUDA devices: ") + std::string(cudaGetErrorString(cr));
        throw std::exception(msg.c_str());
    }

    if (cuda_device_count == 0) {
        cuda_enable = false;
    }
    else{
        std::cout << "Found " << cuda_device_count << " CUDA capable device(s)" << std::endl;
    }

    // Get CUDA device properties
    cudaDeviceProp deviceProp;

    for (int dev = 0; dev < cuda_device_count; ++dev) {
        cr = cudaGetDeviceProperties(&deviceProp, dev);
        strcpy_s(devname, deviceProp.name);
        std::cout << "CUDA GPU " << dev << " \"" << devname << "\" : [BusID " << deviceProp.pciBusID << " | DevID " << deviceProp.pciDeviceID << "]" << std::endl;

        if (cr != cudaSuccess)
        {
            std::string msg = std::string("[InitCuda] Failed to retrieve properties of CUDA device: ") + std::string(cudaGetErrorString(cr));
            throw std::exception(msg.c_str());
        }

        break;
    }
}

cudaError_t RunCudaKernels()
{
    static float t = 0.0f;
    cudaError_t cr = cudaSuccess;

    // populate the 2d texture
    cudaArray* cuArray;
    cr = cudaGraphicsSubResourceGetMappedArray(&cuArray, cuda_interop_resource, 0, 0);
    if (cr != cudaSuccess)
        return cr;

    // kick off the kernel and send the staging buffer cudaLinearMemory as an argument to allow the kernel to write to it
    cr = cuda_texture_2d(texture_rgb_cuda_linear_mem, WIN_WIDTH, WIN_HEIGHT, texture_rgb_cuda_pitch, t);
    if (cr != cudaSuccess)
        return cr;

    // then we want to copy cudaLinearMemory to the D3D texture, via its mapped form : cudaArray
    cr = cudaMemcpy2DToArray(
        cuArray, // dst array
        0, 0,    // offset
        texture_rgb_cuda_linear_mem, texture_rgb_cuda_pitch,        // src
        WIN_WIDTH * 4 * sizeof(UINT8), WIN_HEIGHT, // extent        // sizeof(...) is based on DXGI_FORMAT of texture, e.g. DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM is uint8, while DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT
        cudaMemcpyDeviceToDevice); // kind
    if (cr != cudaSuccess)
        return cr;

    t += 0.1f;

    return cr;
}
```

**load_sample.cpp**

See [here](https://github.com/mindaptiv/Hello-Cube-Windows/blob/master/Tutorial04/Tutorial04.cpp)

**texture_2d.cu**

See [here](https://github.com/NVIDIA/cuda-samples/blob/master/Samples/5_Domain_Specific/simpleD3D11Texture/texture_2d.cu)

**cube_ps.hsls / cube_vs.hsls / cube.fx**

See [here](https://github.com/mindaptiv/Hello-Cube-Windows/blob/master/Tutorial04/Tutorial04.fx)

Comment: If you render your scene to an intermediate texture that isn't the back buffer, modify the CUDA code to read from and write to separate surfaces, then copy the CUDA output to the back buffer, does that work better? I get the sense the problem you're having is read/write contention for the back buffer, so separating the read and write operations so the back buffer is only ever written to may help out.

Comment: I have looked further into the CUDA sample I am using. The issue lies in the fact that my shared resource, while being used for the rendering, is actually being initialized to a constant value. Using `cudaMemset()` is in a way similar to what `ID3D11DeviceContext::ClearRenderTargetView()` does - it sets the memory to a given value.  For the clearing of a RTV I used the RGBA color `{ 0.0f, 0.2f, 0.4f, 1.0f }`, while for the CUDA memory I use `1` (see `cudaMemset(texture_rgb_cuda_linear_mem, 1, texture_rgb_cuda_pitch * height)`). The buffer is completely rewritten thus loosing the drawn cube.

Comment: Actually, no. That is not the problem since the memset happens before my infinite loop where I render things.

Comment: @Alex I have tried what you have suggested. I have added the update. I created two identical `Texture2D` objects - one set to be used by the render target view and the other one registered as a CUDA resource. I use `ID3D11DeviceContext::CopyResource()` to copy the RTV texture to the CUDA shared resource. After I process the resource, again I use the same method to copy back the result. However, it does not change the outcome.

Comment: What is it exactly that you're trying to output to the screen? Say you render the cube: what do you expect the CUDA kernel to do with the rendered image?

Comment: Well, my first attempt is to literally do nothing. That is, the rendered image would just go in and out. This is for testing if the CUDA Direct3D interop works. My next step would be to do basic manipulation (e.g. apply Gaussian blur, swap channels etc.). My ultimate goal is to use Torch C++ (libtorch) for gathering training data and also processing the rendered scene using an AI model. I have already successfully done the CUDA Torch interop (both using TorchScript exported ML model, trained with PyTorch and implementing a model with Torch C++ from scratch), all on the GPU side.

Answer (score 3):

**Update**

As pointed out in the comments, CUDA also seems to disallow using the primary render target (likely meaning the swap chain) as a resource that can be mapped. From the documentation for [`cudaGraphicsD3D11RegisterResource`](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__D3D11.html#group__CUDART__D3D11_1g85d07753780643584b8febab0370623b):

> The primary rendertarget may not be registered with CUDA.

This presents another problem, but it's fairly straightforward to solve this time: simply create a third texture object to act as an intermediary between CUDA and the swap chain. I've modified the steps in the answer to reflect this.

---

I've spent about three or four days refactoring your code and I think I've figured out what's gone wrong here: the CUDA kernel is using a write only back buffer as both input and output.

The swap chain internally creates a surface to do all rendering operations to. This surface needs to be initialized with a `Usage` parameter, which tells DXGI (the underlying API that D3D10/11/12 all talk to) how the resulting surface will be used, which allows the driver to pick the memory location best suited for that usage.

Your swap chain is created with a usage of `DXGI_USAGE_RENDER_TARGET_OUTPUT`. This tells DXGI (and the driver) that you intend to write to this surface as a result of rendering operations. Since you specify no other usages, DXGI (and the driver) assume you will be using this surface as a write-only surface, and the driver/GPU are free to place this surface into a memory space where reading may be slow or entirely disallowed.

This is likely the central issue: because the back buffer surface was created as an assumed write-only surface, attempting to read it, even from the GPU, is likely to fail. When you attempt to read in the rendered scene in the CUDA kernel, the driver/GPU likely realized it couldn't read from that surface, and generated default pixel values for every read performed. That's why a 'null' CUDA kernel outputs a black screen - the input surface is nothing but out-of-bounds/invalid reads, which generate pixel values of zero, which is interpreted by the display as black.

The best mechanism to fix this issue is to separate the CUDA input from the back buffer. This allows your swap chain to sit in write-only memory, while also reading the rendered scene.

To do this, you need to broadly separate your code into four phases:

1. Render your scene to a texture that matches the resolution and pixel format of your back buffer. There are several tutorials on how to render to a texture - follow any one you like.
2. Map the new scene texture and a new intermediate texture as CUDA resources. Create two `cudaSurfaceObject_t` instances to represent the two mapped textures and pass both of these surface objects to your kernel, reading from one and writing to the other with `surf2Dwrite`. This will output your CUDA data directly to the intermediate texture, rather than a buffer you need to copy from later.
3. Copy the intermediate texture to your back buffer via `CopyResource`. This has the side effect of clearing your back buffer.
4. Bind your back buffer render target to the rendering pipeline and render the ImGui components to it. Finish with a call to `Present`.

The important thing to note is the bind flags of the first stage output texture. You need to ensure this texture is both readable by the GPU and writable, which will require that you specify both `D3D11_BIND_RENDER_TARGET` and `D3D11_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE` in the `BindFlags` member of `D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC`.

Stage two can also be done with a `cudaMalloc`ed buffer like what you've done here, but I would strongly recommend using a `cudaSurfaceObject_t` instance as it will allow you to directly write data to the output surface and will use less memory overall. For testing this is not as important, but when you decide to use libTorch saving GPU memory will be very useful.

Comment: Thanks for the effort, much appreciated. I've never used `cudaSurfaceObject_t` and will look into it. In regards to 2) and in particular to the CUDA graphics resources I am assuming that the texture, where I will render my scene to and will provide the data needs to be mapped using `cudaGraphicsMapFlagsReadOnly`, while the other texture (used as a backbuffer) - as a `cudaGraphicsMapFlagsWriteDiscard`, right?

Comment: I have also found the following in regards to the use of `cudaGraphicsD3D11RegisterResource()`: "The primary rendertarget may not be registered with CUDA". I have also a feeling that this may cause some issues.

Comment: Your source and destination textures can be mapped with read-only for source and write-discard for the destination but that's not required. If you do map them that way, the driver can optimize the behavior of the GPU to achieve better throughput.

Comment: In regard to your second comment, you can do the exact same thing as before with render-to-texture for CUDA - create a third texture to act as an intermediary between CUDA and the ImGui rendering path. You might need to draw the CUDA texture as a billboard, but that's relatively simple in comparison to the CUDA interop (and you may be able to work around it via direct copy from CUDA output to back buffer).

Comment: Thanks. I have added an update to my question. I have implemented your suggestions (the best I can currently; I haven't used `cudaSurfaceObject_t` since I still need to read about that and also it should work without it too) but I don't get the result I am looking for. In fact now I cannot even see the CUDA moving pattern that I sometimes use for visually debugging if CUDA is doing something or not.

Comment: Fixed my problem. Thanks. One major issue was that I was mixing the `unsigned char` (8bit) from the format of the D3D11 2D texture with how I was referencing values inside my array (I was all of a sudden using unsigned int`). In addition switching to `cudaSurfaceObject_t` makes working with pixel data a breeze. I will try to remove the extra texture that I created based on your suggestion to see if that is working also.